# Every string as param for SecretKeySpec?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Can I use every possible String to create a new `SecretKeySpec`? Or will it weaken the entire encryption?

```
byte[] raw = password.getBytes();
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be relatively weak to use the password bytes directly. At the very least you'll want to run them through a strong hash. And throw in a salt, some array of bytes that you can reproduce for the scenario (either static for your app or better something like a fixed user id).

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digest.update(password.getBytes());
digest.update(salt);
byte[] raw = digest.digest();
```

If you really want to make it harder to brute force the password, you could make the hashing more complicated. This for example will only add a few tens of milliseconds for legitimate use cases, however it'll significantly slow down a brute force attack:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 34000; i++) {
    digest.reset();
    digest.update(raw);
    raw = digest.digest();
}
```

Ideally you make sure the password is strong as well (length, complexity, mix of upper/lower/number characters). If it's a simple word or short enough then the attack is still going to be easy. Don't trust the obscurity of this hashing either, it doesn't make it any safer. It's use of strong passwords and strong hashing that matter.

To get the full benefit of 128-bit AES the password would need to be around 20 characters long, however 8 to 12 will probably suffice for the majority of concerns. If you're working for my bank please use 20 or more though.

Comment: Thank you for this good answer. Salt and Hash would not be necessary if you enter a very strong password, correct? 

Greetz from your bank ;)

Comment: I'd still use at least a hash that has an output the size of an AES key, especially since that will at least always give you a key that's the right size. Technically speaking a very strong password will still generate a weaker key than if it were hashed (unless the password is literally just 16 securely generated random characters with byte values from 0 to 255). People are always developing new ways to attack weaker systems and computers are continually getting faster. There are standards around this too, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2 for details.